# Why conda list caused AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag' error?

Tags: python, enums, conda, attributeerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/fzy/python/corepython/tensorflow-test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "E:\anacoda\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "E:\anacoda\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "E:\anacoda\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "E:\anacoda\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "E:\anacoda\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
    import re
  File "E:\anacoda\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

[image]

I install tensorflow and found this error,but I didn't know how conda cause it.
[image]

Comment: Please show your source code

Answer (score 1):

As a guess, one of the following things happened:

- `pip install enum` -- a different `enum` package than the stdlib version which is shadowing the stdlib version
- `enum.py` file -- you have created an `enum.py` file which is shadowing the stdlib version
- you have somehow deleted the `enum.py` that comes with the stdlib